# How to add multiple relying parties (IdP) to my Spring Boot 3 application at runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0

My application act as a portal that provides an option to customers to setup their own SSO (SAML2.0 and OpenID) configuration with their IdP of choice at the time of registration. Spring Security allows the configuration for SAML with `RelyingPartyRegistration`. I can be able to setup multiple IDPs at the time of development. However, I could not find a way to achieve this solution at the time of runtime.

How can I dynamically configure my application to accept customer's IDP details (SAML Configuration) and store them in database and allow them to login with their IDP and SAML protocol? Does Spring security or any other library provides such SAML abstraction?